# Debug login in Laravel Nova - show always invalid credentials error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have in the nova/auth/ directory the login view `login.blade.php` that has a post request to the `nova.login` route:

```
<form
    method="POST"
    action="{{ route('nova.login') }}"
>
```

The nova.login route has this action associated:

```
nova.login            | Laravel\Nova\Http\Controllers\LoginController@login
```

However this file is not in the folder structure. Already run `php artisan vendor:publish` but still doesn't appear.

However I don't have the nova `LoginController` in my project. Do you know how to access that file? I'm asking this because I'm having an invalid credentials error even entering the correct credentials. So I'm tryign to debug to understand what's the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the official installation guide.

```
php artisan nova:install
php artisan migrate
```

Maybe it might be cached too, please try following commands

```
php artisan nova:publish
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

[Nova Installation Docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/installation.html)